# patchValue with { emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true } triggers valueChanges in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Reset button which resets the value of domain with patchValue

```
onReset() {      
    this.addModelForm.patchValue({ domain: '', emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true}); 
}
```

and this is the valueChanges method for domain :

```
this.addModelForm.get('domain').valueChanges.subscribe(domainId => {
    console.log("value changed!")
});
```

It prints "value changed!" on console 2 times. I don't want to trigger the valueChanges method. emitEvent is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using patchValue on FormGroup It should be like this:

**Try this:**

```
 this.addModelForm.patchValue( { domain: '' },{emitEvent: false});
```

Answer (score 3):

What has worked for me is a construct like this, it also works well in unit tests.

```
programmaticUpdate = false; // prevents excessive event emission and infinite loops

// ...

private suppressEvents(callback: () => void) {
  this.programmaticUpdate = true;
  try {
    callback();
  } finally {
    this.programmaticUpdate = false;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
this.suppressEvents(() => {
  this.addModelForm.patchValue({ domain: '' }); 
});
```

And don't forget to ignore programmatic `valueChanges` like this:

```
this.addModelForm.get('domain').valueChanges.pipe(
  filter(() => !this.programmaticUpdate), // ignore programmatic updates
  takeUntil(this.destroy$), // best practice, read about it online
).subscribe(domainId => {
  console.log("value changed!")
});
```

`emitEvent` has never worked for me, even today with Angular 15.

*Source: 6 years of Angular experience.*